# regular expressions, php, and preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to program a 'chat bot' for a custom chatroom i'm working on right now and I'm having some trouble with matching up the expressions.

RIght now, everything returns back as the error message. If I switch everything over to a get variable and test on the page itself, it'll show four or five error messages and then the actual message. which I'm taking to mean that the pregmatch and loop are just sending the first result back. How can i avoid that?

```
    include('../lib/bootstrap.php');
if(!isset($_POST['input']))
{
    return false;   
}
else
{
    $error = "UNKNOWN COMMAND";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO slconsole(uid, input, output) VALUES (1, :input, :output)";
    $que = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $que->bindParam(':input', $_POST['input']);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('robotsarereal.xml');
    foreach($xml->topic as $topic)
    {
        foreach($topic->input as $input)
        {
                $input = strtolower($input);
                $uinput = strtolower($_POST['input']);
                if(preg_match('/{$input}/', $uinput, $matches))
                {
                    foreach($matches[0] as $match)
                    {
                        if($match == $input)
                        {
                            foreach($topic->output as $output)
                            {
                            $que->bindParam(':output', $output);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{ $que->bindParam(':output', $error);}
        }
    }
    try { $que->execute(); } catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
}
```

Comment: These "error messages" you speak of, what are they?

Comment: You're binding `':output'` to a variable that's out of scope by the time you call `execute()` (and besides which, what's the point in rebinding it multiple times - especially if you only execute once)?

Comment: @Sammitch, the $error variable. There's no error message becauses the error variable.